# Why is the url showing /ServletName though what is displayed is from jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a servlet where I get data from Sql Server using `ResultSet`. I use 
`request.setAttribute("list", list);
request.getRequestDispatcher("Display.jsp").forward(request, response);` to display as a table in the jsp.

But in the omnibox of chrome I see /ServletName instead of /JSPName.jsp. The table is displayed in the jsp using `foreach` based on the `list` received from servlet.

This is the servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    Connection connection = null;
    Statement stmt = null;



    try {
        StringBuffer data = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=DesktopScreen","sa","sa123");
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        String query = "select * from ClientLogin";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String UniqueId,ClientId,RequestedDateTime,ConnectionStatus;
            UniqueId = rs.getString("UniqueID");
            ClientId = rs.getString("ClientId");
            RequestedDateTime = rs.getString("RequestDateTime");
            ConnectionStatus = rs.getString("ConnectionStatus");
            BeanClass beanClass = new BeanClass();
            beanClass.setUniqueId(UniqueId);
            beanClass.setClientId(ClientId);
            beanClass.setConnectionStatus(ConnectionStatus);
            beanClass.setRequestDateTime(RequestedDateTime);

            list.add(beanClass);

        }
        request.setAttribute("list", list);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("Display.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {

        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

This is Display.jsp:

```
<table border ="1" style="border: border-collapse">
        <tr><td>UniqueId</td><td>ClientId</td><td>Request Date and Time</td><td>Connection Status</td></tr>
    <c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
        <tr>
            <td>${item.getUniqueId()}</td>
            <td>${item.getClientId()}</td>
            <td>${item.getRequestDateTime()}</td>
            <td>${item.getConnectionStatus()}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

Comment: `forward` method doesn't change the url of the browser. try [`sendRedirect`](http://www.javatpoint.com/sendRedirect()-method). Read [Difference between SendRedirect() and Forward() in JSP Servlet](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/sendredirect-forward-jsp-servlet.html#ixzz41izgW1fO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser has requested for the servlet url and the servlet has forwared it to jsp. Your browswer does not know that. This is because you are using `[requestDispatcher.forward()][1]` method. Check the image from [thejavageek.com](http://www.thejavageek.com/java-servlets-jsp-tutorials/)

[image]

This is what happens

- Browser requests the servlet.
- Servlet forwards the task to jsp.(Browser doesn't know that)
- Broswer still thinks the response has come from servlet and not jsp.

If you want the url to be shown in browser, then you need to user [response.sendRedirect()](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/12/15/redirect-request-servlets/) which is explained in image below

[image]

If you use `response.sendRedirect()`, below steps will happen.

- Your browser requests servlet.
- Servlet calls response.sendredirect();
- Browser will make another request to another resource and url will be changed in the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

When you use requestDispatcher.forward(); the resources are forwarded within the server from where the call is made. This is done by container internally and client or browser is not involved in it.